# Parse.com add userImage to PFSignUpViewController and remove phone number

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Hello i´m new to parse and i´m building an app with a user management. I did it  like described on the parse.com homepage. Everything works fine.

But i want to add a field where the user can upload an image. I tried to add a photoButton where the user can take a photo. But how can i upload and save the image to the user in the backend.

I also want to remove the phone number. Is it possible to do this in PFSignUpViewController? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a PFFile object to upload the image on parse.

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.5f);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];


[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFObject* photoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PthotosObject"];
        [photoObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

        [photoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }
            else{
                // Error
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

For the Number field,

Default configuration of the `PFSignUpViewController` comes with username,password,email,signup button & dismiss button, You must have customised it.

Refer this [link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface-pfsignupviewcontroller) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To get a user image, you get the image from the client (photo-picker or whatever), get the data from the image (`UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`), create a PFFile with the data (`PFFile fileWithName:data:`), save that file assign the PFFile object to a column in your user (call it imageFile or something like that), and save the user.

For the phone number, you can control the fields the signup view controller uses with the `additionalFields` property...

```
signUpController.fields = (PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword
                          | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton
                          | PFSignUpFieldsEmail
                          | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional
                          | PFSignUpFieldsDismissButton);
```

Removing any of those removes the field.